# Angualr componen't doesnt mount if effects return cached results

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to cache http requests to reduce traffic, in Task effect I'm checking if user tasks already retrieved. But when I do that, when I return cached tasks, component doesn't render. If you remove it and make http request again, it continue to work.

this is TasksEffect class

```js
@Injectable()
export class TasksEffect {
  @Effect() fetchEffects = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(TaskListActions.FETCH_TASKS),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select('tasksModule')),
    switchMap(([action, tasksModule]) => {
      if (tasksModule.tasks.length) {
        return of(new TaskListActions.SetTasks([...tasksModule.tasks]));
      }
      return this.taskService.fetchTasks((action as TaskListActions.FetchTasks).interval)
        .pipe(
          catchError(err => of(err)),
          switchMap(tasks => of(new TaskListActions.SetTasks(tasks))),
        );
    })
  );

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService, private store: Store<fromTasks.AppState>, private actions$: Actions) {
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code ? if it so how can I fix it ? Also is there better approach to cache http request like memoize in react

Comment: `shareReplay()` of rxjs operator is useful for caching. First subscriber getting data from http request, and later all subscribers gets cached data only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `catchError(err => of(err))` should be after `switchMap`, because in case of an error the error will be reduced as `TaskListActions.SetTasks`.

try like that, if it doesn't work - let me know in the comments. You need to check other places then, the effect is simple, perhaps `this.taskService.fetchTasks` has an issue.

```js
@Injectable()
export class TasksEffect {
    @Effect() fetchEffects = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(TaskListActions.FETCH_TASKS),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.select('tasksModule')),
        switchMap(([action, tasksModule]) => {
            if (tasksModule.tasks && tasksModule.tasks.length) {
                return of(new TaskListActions.SetTasks([...tasksModule.tasks]));
            }
            return this.taskService.fetchTasks((action as TaskListActions.FetchTasks).interval)
                .pipe(
                    map(tasks => new TaskListActions.SetTasks(tasks)),
                    catchError(err => of(err)),
                );
        })
    );

    constructor(private taskService: TaskService, private store: Store<fromTasks.AppState>, private actions$: Actions) {
    }
}
```